# Dynamic Item in JQuery Mobile List View - data.prevPage.attr

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

Adding dynamic option to JQM listview was successful in `page1`. After adding it, listview was refresh:

```
$('#list').listview('refresh');
```

Options was linked to `page2`. In `page2` I have `pagebeforeshow` event:

```
$('#page2').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

`data.prevPage.attr('id')` is undefined when the option selected was the one added dynamically. But for the other option, no problem at all.

Why can't I get `page1` id when selecting dynamically added option in listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work, take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/c2dU4/. I have recreated your case and everything is working just fine.

Example:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#custom-list').append('<li><a href="#second">Link 4</a></li>');
    $('#custom-list').listview('refresh');
});

$("#second").live('pagebeforeshow', function (e,data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

Are you maybe trying to pass some additional data through a href? And can you show us more of your code?